# Angular 8 routing to 404 using wildcard '**' in child module overrides parent module routing to other dynamic modules?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Question might seem complicated, so:

*Module setup:*

```
- General (few common components and 404 page template)
- App (the app)
   |___Main (main www)
   |     |___General (uses)
   |___[DYNAMIC] Admin (admin panel)
         |___General (uses)
```

*Routing modules:*

**App**

Is basically `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, all further stuff happens in sub-modules:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule) }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Main**

Since `Main` is child of `App` module, its empty path `''` (or `'/'`) will be placed there.
`MainComponent` is page header with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` for content. By default it is filled with `HomeComponent` (route `''`), but can also match to `'/page1'` or `'/page2'`. Now notice that there is `'**'` wildcard that is supposed to catch all unmatched paths and show them in `MainComponent` outlet (so that there is 404 inside page with header).

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component },
            { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component },
            { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutingModule { }
```

**Admin [DYNAMIC]**

Similar to `Main` but loaded dynamically from `App`. Also has internal 404 wildcard.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'page1', component: AdminPage1Component },
            { path: 'page2', component: AdminPage2Component },
            { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

The problem is that since `Main` routing starts as `''` (`'/'`) its 404 wildcard `'**'` shadows `App` module's `'/admin'` path and we end up with 404 inside `MainComponent` (the one with header). It happens both when trying to link from withing `MainComponent` to /admin and when typing path into browser. `Main` module shadows parent routing.

Requirement is that `Main` module can't know about `Admin` module (so I can't lazy load Admin module from `Main` module, that's why it is placed in `App` module), but a the same time (`Main` module) can have wildcard for 404.

I know I could make additional path like:

```
main/page1
main/page2
admin/page1
admin/page2
```

...but I really want it to be:

```
page1
page2
admin/page1
admin/page2
```

Is there a solution for child module wildcard to not shadow parent?

Answer (score 0):

Specify `main` module in `app-routing.module.ts`

such as

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
'path': '',
'loadChildren': () => import('./modules/home/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule)
},
{ path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule) }

];
```

Make sure it is above admin module

Comment: So this will actually work if I make both Main and Admin modules dynamic and place '/admin' BEFORE '/' in App routing (its inverse of what You said). Your answer reminded me of resolution ordering and I made it work like described above - but that makes BOTH modules dynamic. The moment I import Main module into App (using 'imports' in @NgModule) Main module routing will shadow '/admin' path - even if it's before it, like described.